# Android API 22 | java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyGenerator RSA implementation not found

Tags: java, android, encryption, realm

I have an Android app that is to be published, and today trying on a device Moto G, running the API 22, I came across the following error:

> ***java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyGenerator RSA***
>   ***implementation not found***

It is known that the same application is running normally smoothly on newer devices API 23+

Querying the Google documentation, I saw that the AES algorithm is supported since API +1, I do not understand what is happening.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

By the way, I'm trying to generate the key to encrypt Realm data.

```
private static final String KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_NAME = "AndroidKeyStore";
public void generateKeyInKeystore() {
        final KeyGenerator keyGenerator;
        try {
            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(
                    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES,
                    KEYSTORE_PROVIDER_NAME);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchProviderException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        final KeyGenParameterSpec keySpec;

        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                keySpec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                        KEY_ALIAS,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                        .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                        .build();
                keyGenerator.init(keySpec);
            }
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        keyGenerator.generateKey();

    }
```

[image: Here a Stack Trace with device info]

Comment: Try using SpongyCastle

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Can you show me any examples that i can use this lib?

Comment: The exception in your title doesn't match the exception in your question. So which is it?

Answer (score 6):

Well, according to the Android official developer guide, since your Cipher combination is "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding" it supports API level 23+. Since your app running with API level 22 it doesn't support "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding" Cypher.

If you want to support below API levels consider using one of the Ciphers "RSA/ECB/NoPadding" or "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding". They do support API level 18+

Find more details in **Cypher** and **KeyGenerator** sections in [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html#SecurityFeatures) official guide.